# Different behaviour when running multiple Cypress specs via open and run commands

Tags: cypress

I have a simple spec that visits a site and logs in like below:

```
it ('Visits the site as logged in user', function () {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')
  cy.get('#username').type(Cypress.env('username'))
  cy.get('#password').type(Cypress.env('password'))
  cy.get('#submit').click()
  cy.contains('logout')
})
```

This works fine when I run it on it's own.  I make a second spec file and copy the contents of the first spec file. Now I have 2 specs that do the same thing.  If I run `npx cypress open` and run all specs then both specs run successfully.  However I do `npx cypress run` then the second spec fails because cookies or session or something hasn't been cleared and when the site is visited it is already logged in so does not display the log in page.

From what I've read cookies and I assume everything else should be cleared between specs.  The difference between `open` and `run` is also concerning as I feel they should be consistent (note that using `--headed` option for run does not change behaviour for `run`).

I have tried executing both `cy.clearCookies() and cy.clearLocalStorage()` before the tests but this does not change anything.

Has anyone else encountered similar problems and know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the failure you encounter? Have you looked at the captured video?

Comment: The failure is that the site is already logged into from the previous spec so the inputs for log in are not available.

Comment: Sounds like cookie issues introduced in 3.5.0, and not yet fully resolved probably until the version that will come after 3.6.0.

Comment: Are you using electron to test also when running tests through `cypress open`?